# How to get Bluetooth back in panel?

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

After install the drivers and stuff for a 3.5 inch LCD screen, my RPis Bluetooth seems to be disabled... The applet doesn't show in the panel like the wifi and volume does. Before the installation everything worked fine.

Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out after a few hours of frustration. What I did was Menu>Preferences>Raspberry Pi Configuration>Interfaces>Enable 'Serial Port' and 'Serial Console'. >Reboot

Comment: I know that this is more than a year late, but please accept your answer. You'll get the reputation and this question will stop popping up periodically.